# как вставить скрипт, чтоб он не открывался на всю страницу

Tags: javascript, html, виджет

Есть скрипт, виджет по продаже билетов:

```
<script src="//widget.unitiki.com/v2/widget.js"></script>
```

Подскажите как сделать так чтоб по клику на него на кнопку найти, он не открывался на всю страницу закрывая все остальное, а открывался на всю ширину экрана и растягивался в низ на столько сколько ему нужно, но при этом в верху и снизу от него оставались видны другие элементы на странице, нижние сдвигались в низ под виджет

Comment: Никак. Такое поведение заложено внутри скрипта. Обратитесь к автору скрипта, что бы доработали.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - это использовать CSS для решения этой задачи. Найди селектор элемента модального окна и переопредели его ширину и высоту, возможно, тебе понадобятся такие свойства как `min-content`, `max-content` или просто поля в процентном соотношении по всем сторонам. Варианты есть, нужно найти лучший.

Обрати внимание на сами стили, где они добавляются? Учитывая, что ты привел только js файл, наверное прям в атрибуте `style`. В таком случае перебей их специфичность ключевым слово `!important`.